# More efficient dot-product with 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, numpy, performance

My `user_factors` and `item_factors` are of `numpy.ndarray` type. I want to efficiently calculate dot-product between a row of `user_factors` and each row of `item_factors`, and store the result in a `numpy.ndarray`. This is how I do it:

```
import numpy as np

...

user_coordinates = user_factors[user_id]

scores = []

for i in range(len(item_factors)):
    item_coordinates = item_factors[i]
    score = sum(i[0] * i[1] for i in zip(user_coordinates, item_coordinates))
    scores.append(score)


np_scores = np.hstack(scores)
```

Could this be done more efficiently (perhaps without the  `list` to `numpy.ndarray` conversion at the end)?

Comment: Isn't this the dot product of a 2d array (item_factors) and 1d array (user_coordinates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume some data

```
np.random.seed(0)
user_coordinates = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10,))
item_factors = np.random.randint(0, 10, (15, 10))
```

Your result will then be

```
>>> np_scores
array([220, 156, 133, 178, 205, 269, 164, 184,  98, 159, 103, 182, 194,
       157, 188])
```

You can achieve the same in a one-liner straight with numpy:

```
>>> item_factors.dot(user_coordinates)
array([220, 156, 133, 178, 205, 269, 164, 184,  98, 159, 103, 182, 194,
       157, 188])
```

The documentation of [`numpy.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) says:

> - If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over the last axis of a and b.

Answer (score 1):

dot products between i-th row of A and j_th row of B are given in C_{ij}:

```
A=np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3))
B=np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3))
C=np.dot(A,B.T)
```

If you want to calculate the dot product between a specific row of A, say 2nd, and all the rows of B, then:

```
C = np.dot(A[1,:], B.T)
```